# .htaccess to redirect jpg to a webpage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, jpeg

With my site, I have www.mysite.com/images/1.jpg and www.mysite.com/pixels/1.jpg

I would like for the .htaccess to redirect ANY jpg (just jpgs) image throughout my entire website to redirect to www.mysite.com/directory/

I had a .htaccess file that did this, but then I couldn't use the image on my own website like  it would just be a blank box but if I visited the exact url of the image, it took me to www.mysite.com/directory/

The reason for this is like if someone finds the images of mine on Google Images or on Tumblr or another website, once they click the image and visit the url of the image on my site, it will redirect them to a directory like www.mysite.com/directory/

I hope I explained this well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you want to check the referer. It's one of the HTTP request headers that tells the webserver what URL they were at that referred them to what they're requesting. Also keep in mind that referers can be forged. You can add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.jpg$ /directory/ [L,R=302.NC]
```

Comment: I don't want anyone to be able to view the image at www.mysite.com/image/1.jpg even if they're directed there from my own site, if that makes sense.

So I'd like <img src="/image/1.jpg"> to display the photo. But if I have <a href="/image/1.jpg><img src="/image/1.jpg"></a> I want the image to display, but if they click the image, I want it to send them to www.mysite.com/directory if that is possible.

Comment: @StauntonAllen The server can't tell if a browser requested an image to **display it on a page** vs a browser requested an image to **just display the image**. On the server's end **they look 100% identical**.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for explaining that to me. I assumed it could tell a difference. I have seen other websites that redirect any .jpg file to their home page, but still display their images on the site. I figured it had something to do with their .htaccess file but I guess they used another method.

Comment: @StauntonAllen You can use the referer to not show the image if they click a link of the image from somewhere *other* than your site, but you can't differentiate a page load from your site vs clicking a link from your site. The request looks identical. There's probably some javascript way of preventing loading only an the image and allowing only image loads from page loads.

Comment: Ok, so then I won't have any knowledge of it redirecting if I try it myself, unless I actually click on a link to the .jpg from a different site? Also, my site is a hosted subdomain. So would I change https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/ to https?://(www\.)?mysite.domain\.com/ ? and does it matter that it says https if my site is http?

Comment: @StauntonAllen If there is no "www" for your site, then you can just get rid of it and use whatever your hostname is. The `?` after the "s" in "https" means the "s" is optional. And you can test it by copying the URL of one of your images, and just load it in a new browser tab, it should not allow you to see the image.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help! It is working perfectly now. I'm extremely new to htaccess and servers, and anything beyond html/css confuses me, but I need to have this site up in the next two weeks and you have helped so much, so thank you so much for your patience with me and all your explanations and help!